# How to replace item in lists in a list in Python

Tags: python, list, for-loop, nested-lists

Now i just want to replace the min, max value with the x in the table.... and i dont know how to ...

```
for i in table[1:]:
    mn = min(i) if min(i) < mn else mn 
    mx = max(i) if max(i) > mx else mx
    x = (mn+mx)/2
```

Comment: Framing your question in more concise way would increase chances of getting some help. Try describing only the problem you're having and be as clear as possible. No need to state that you are new to python - there's no such thing as dumb question, you're not expected to know everything.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. I was just a bit scared :)

Answer (score 1):

The following should work:

```
def remove_outliers(table):
    mx = max(map(max, table))
    mn = min(map(min, table))
    avg = (mx + mn) / 2

    for row in table:
        row[:] = [avg if x in (mx, mn) else x for x in row]
    # OR
    for row in table:
        for i, x in enumerate(row):
            if x in (mx, mn):
                row[i] = avg
```

**`max(map(max, table))`:** applies the `max` function to each row in `table`, and takes the `max` of all those "maxes".

**`row[:] = ...`:** slice-assignment. This is a mutation on the `row` object. Simply `row = ...` would just rebind the loop variable without affecting the list object that is still indexed by `table`.

**`[avg if x in (mx, mn) else x for x in row]`:** general conditional list comprehension. Fairly self-explanatory.

Comment: Thank you so much, if possible can you explain this part for me: row[:] ?? What does this mean

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `numpy` check out the `clip` function (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.clip.html).